# SQL Profiler not connecting to my server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

My SQL Profiler was working previously against my Server. I have not (AFAIK) made any modifications to the configuration of my server.

When I go into SQL Profiler I attempt to "Connect to SQL Server", I enter my SQL Server (which is on my local dev machine), I get the error

> To connect to this server you must use SQL Server Management Studio or Sql Server Management Objects

How do I resolve this?

I'm using SQL Profiler 8.00.2039
SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote up the whole question and got to the end and realized the answer:

Problem was I was using SQL Profiler 8, I should have been using SQL Profiler 9

Comment: Thought I'd post it here because other people may have the same "brain-fart"